# WorldPay Payment Integration using PHP and direct XML method curl API return blank page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway, curl

I m  trying to implement worldpay on a PHP site using XML direct method but whenever I try to connect I get blank pag.. Can you tell me were you testing the payment gateway on live site.
Code:

```
    $url = 'https://secure.worldpay.com/sso/public/auth/login.html?serviceIdentifier=merchantadmin';
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username
:password");
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml );
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  // curl_close($ch);
  // echo json_encode($result);
  // exit;
return $this->_pageFactory->create();
```

How to solve it? 
Anyone can help me to solve this
i was used this [payment-gateway](http://support.worldpay.com/support/kb/gg/corporate-gateway-guide/content/directintegration/quickstart.htm) .

Comment: make sure you are using this api token url `/rest/V1/integration/admin/token`

Comment: I used my payment gateway  administration Interface  url

Comment: try this one **$adminUrl = "127.0.0.1/your_Magento_dir/rest/V1/integration/admin/token"**

Comment: assuming you are running on localhost 127.0.0.1

Comment: modify your $adminUrl value like that one

Comment: No, i m running in the live server

Comment: can you include the value of your  $adminUrl

Comment: try this `$adminUrl="http://secure-test.worldpay.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token"`

Comment: i will check and update you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89711/discussion-between-magefms-and-divya-sekar).

Comment: just let me know if it did not work

Comment: its not working now also it gives null  https://prnt.sc/mkwj6

Comment: @divyasekar you have which error faing currently?

Comment: it does not generate token its gives null value @rakesh

Comment: otherwise it give 401 authorized error @rakesk

Comment: may be help you this link check it 
https://github.com/Worldpay/worldpay-magento

Comment: you have checked  your code is correct? no any error ?

Comment: hi @divyasekar you can check below link i have search for you 
https://github.com/Worldpay/Worldpay-Magento2-CG?utm_source=mageplaza&utm_medium=mageplaza&utm_campaign=mageplaza-review&utm_content=Worldpay%20Corporate%20Gateway

Comment: i will check and update u @rakesh

Comment: @divyasekar why are you trying to connect to Worldpay admin interface? What goals are you want to achieve?

Comment: @divyasekar Try UTF-8 encoding. See this screenshot : https://www.screencast.com/t/DynJnygUhL

Comment: i will tried and update you @Sanjay Gohil

Comment: i was return a blank page @sanjay

Comment: i dont have a  sanbox account can u send a  link  for sanbox

Comment: @divyasekar In my case I have face cross browsing issue so I have solved using this code check screenshot :https://www.screencast.com/t/pgNPcXm3

Comment: no i was again execute a blank page