# Magento 2: Can I response with a redirect on REST API?

Tags: magento2, redirect, rest-api, response

I have an API endpoint that expects a **GET request**.
On some scenarios, I want to be able to perform a redirect instead of responding with a result.

e.g., If you'll open the API endpoint URL in a browser, you'll be redirected to a specific page.

- I **KNOW** that I can use a controller for that instead of REST API, but this is the current situation & I need to solve it without changing the endpoint URL.
- I tried to use `Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory` & return a `TYPE_REDIRECT` response from the API method, but it just returns an empty array & not redirecting.

  ---

Any idea?

Comment: post your execute function with the code

Comment: maybe put your type_redirect inside your execute method

Comment: There is no execute method... it's a REST API, not a controller...

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to this. Create a around plugin of **Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest** class. Your around plugin will look like below.

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resultFactory,     
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect     
    ) 
{
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
    $this->redirect = $redirect;
}

public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest $subject, $proceed) 
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT
        );

    You can check request type from native $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
    if(Your condition)
    {
       $this->messageManager->addWarningMessage(__('You cannot access the endpoint browser directly.'));
       $result = $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl());
    } else {
        $result = $proceed();
    }

    return $result;

}
```

}

I don't know if it can be done with before plugin. Let me know if you need further help. Happy Coding :)

Comment: i was struck with [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261724/curl-api-token-return-null-magento-2) can u plz help to solve it @Ram

Comment: Seems a bit too much to me, I hoped that there's an out-of-the-box way to achieve that. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: Welcome @Pini :)

Answer (score 0):

Please, check this implementation for REST API endpoint

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
) {
    $this->response = $response;
}

// Your handling method
public function handle() {
    $this->response->setRedirect('...YOUR URL...')->sendResponse();
}
```