# Get Tax class name from id in magento2

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-class

I have used below code to get tax class name from id.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$taxClassObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Tax\Model\TaxClass\Source \Product');

$taxid = 2;
echo $taxName =  $taxClassObj->getOptionText($taxid);
```

This returns the Options text from id that is "Taxable Goods"

How to get the Id from Text?

Can we get Tax class id(value) from the tax class name?

Can anyone look into this and update your thoughts. thanks

Comment: you should have all information in `$taxClassess`, that's an array with label / value, while label is the taxClassId and label the name

Comment: @HelgeB, yes I have all options in that variable, but can we get the id from a text(class name)?

Comment: Did you try something like this? `foreach ($taxClassess as $taxclass){ if ($taxclass['label'] == 'class name') $myTaxId = $taxclass['value']; }`

Comment: i was stuck with [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261724/curl-api-token-return-null-magento-2) can u plz help me to solve it @HelgeB

Comment: @HelgeB, yes that will work, but is there any default functions to get from repository or something other way?

Comment: I don't know such a function, since the usecase is a little unusal inmho because everywhere the tax class id is used

Comment: @HelgeB, can we set custom tax_amount for quote item? here is my question,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart

Answer (score 1):

I use this in a plugin but shoud work in every class:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxClassKeyInterface;

class PluginName
{
    ....

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxClassManagementInterface $taxClassManagementInterface,
        \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxClassKeyInterfaceFactory $taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->taxClassManagementInterface = $taxClassManagementInterface;
        $this->taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory = $taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    ....

    public function getTaxClassId($clasName){
        $taxClassId = $this->taxClassManagementInterface->getTaxClassId(
            $this->taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory->create()
                ->setType(TaxClassKeyInterface::TYPE_NAME)
                ->setValue($clasName)
        );
        return $taxClassId;
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: in Magento 2.4.4. use `use Magento\Tax\Model\TaxClass\KeyFactory as TaxClassKeyInterfaceFactory; 
`